# the regular expressions in tcl/expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a question about regular expressions in expect,

I use the following expression:

```
expect {
    -re "PLAYER: (RON)_(\[0-9]*)"
    ###do something using switch
}
```

to match the following format of output `"PLAYER:RON_90"`, the first part of the output is always the same: `"PLAYER:RON_"`, but the second part of it(the name after the first part) is changing alawys, sometimes is `PLAYER:RON_90`, sometimes is `PLAYER:RON_87`, `PLAYER:RON_75`, I want to do different action based on the first number of the second part, for example: if it is `PLAYER:RON_second part`(90 to 99), do action 1, if it is `PLAYER:RON_second part`(80 to 89),do action 2, if it is `PLAYER:RON_second part`(70 to 79), do action 3.

how to achive it? modify the regular expressions? or some other ways? can anyone help?

Comment: and also if the output is PLAYER:RON_106, the first number should be 10, then how to achieve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
expect {
    -re {PLAYER RON_(\d+)} {
}
```

The notation \d+ means "at least one decimal digit".

UPDATE:

```
expect -re {PLAYER RON_(\d+)} {
    set playerNumber $expect_out(1,string)
    set playerGroup [expr {$playerNumber / 10}]
    switch -- $playerGroup {
        8 { puts "80-89" }
        9 { puts "90-99" }
        10 { puts "100-109" }
    }
}
```

If we have a match, then the playerNumber will be the number right after the `RON_` and **playerGroup** will be what you are looking for.

Comment: +1. It might be better to use `switch -glob` and patterns like `8*` and `9*`.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage:

> If a process produced the output "abbbcabkkkka\n", the result of:
>
> ```
> expect -indices -re "b(b*).*(k+)"
> ```
>
> is as if the following statements had executed:
>
> ```
> set expect_out(0,start) 1
> set expect_out(0,end) 10
> set expect_out(0,string) bbbcabkkkk
> set expect_out(1,start) 2
> set expect_out(1,end) 3
> set expect_out(1,string) bb
> set expect_out(2,start) 10
> set expect_out(2,end) 10
> set expect_out(2,string) k
> set expect_out(buffer) abbbcabkkkk
> ```

So, for the following regular expression...

```
    -re "PLAYER: (RON)_(\[0-9])(\[0-9]+)"
```

...you could do this:

```
    if {[info exists expect_out(1,string)]} {
        switch -- $expect_out(1,string) {
            case "9":
                // ...
            case "8":
                // ...
            case "7":
                // ...
        }
    }
```

And similarly you can see the "extra" digits by checking `[info exists expect_out(2,string)]`.

Comment: but for example, if the output is PLAYER: (RON)_92, does your -re "PLAYER: (RON)_(\[0-9]\[0-9])(\[0-9]*)" matches?

Comment: Yes.  The ``*`` means "zero or more".

Comment: @ratzip I updated the answer after realizing you only care about the numbers in groups of tens, e.g. 90-99. Note that ``+`` means 1 or more, so you're matching a number with at least 2 digits.